# TypeError: undefined is not a function while returning resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i googled it before asking here but no luck.

I am trying to invoke rest service using ngresource but app UI is not launching because it is breaking with

```
05-13 02:16:08.011 2402-2402/com.app.mvalt I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(25642)] "TypeError: undefined is not a function
                                                           at Object.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/services.js:8:9)
                                                           at Object.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
                                                           at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17615:37)
                                                           at Object.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17762:17)
                                                           at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17580:37
                                                           at getService (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17721:39)
                                                           at Object.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:17753:13)
                                                           at extend.instance (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22311:34)
                                                           at nodeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21421:36)
                                                           at compositeLinkFn (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:20853:13)", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (25642)
```

Here is my service.js:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('BlankFactory', [function(){
    }])

.factory('User', [function($resource){
    return $resource('http://1.2.3.4:1234/UASAPI/userRegistration');
    }])

.service('BlankService', [function(){
    }]);
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <style type="text/css">
      .platform-ios .manual-ios-statusbar-padding{
        padding-top:20px;
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding{
        padding-top:0px; 
      }
      .manual-remove-top-padding .scroll{
        padding-top:0px !important;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>

    <!-- Only required for Tab projects w/ pages in multiple tabs 
    <script src="lib/ionicuirouter/ionicUIRouter.js"></script>
    -->

  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
  <div>
    <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable bar-balanced">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I donwloaded angular-resource.min.js from http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.16/angular-resource.min.js

Here is my app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Could someone help in what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User` factory has problem, you haven't injected `$resource` object before using it in factory function.

```
.factory('User', ['$resource', //<-- $resource dependency was missing here.
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://1.2.3.4:1234/UASAPI/userRegistration');
  }
])
```

> Also make sure, angular file version & `ng-resource` version should
>   not get mismatch.